# VTD-XML : Exception IN com.ximpleware.ParseException: XML decl error: Can't switch encoding to UTF-8

Tags: xml, scala, utf-16, vtd-xml

I have xml with UTF-16 encoding and I have written code in Scala to parse it using VTD-GEN lib and getting an below exception.
Any help would be really appreciable.
Exception in thread "main" com.ximpleware.ParseException: XML decl error: Can't switch encoding to UTF-8.

BELOW IS CODE SNIPPET

```
val xml = Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/sample.xml")).mkString.
val xmlStr = extractApnXML(xml)
println(xmlStr)
val encodingStr = identifyEncoding(xmlStr.substring(0, 50))
println("Encoding : " + encodingStr) //Encoding : utf-16be
val bytes = xml.getBytes(encodingStr)

val vtdGen = new VTDGen
vtdGen.setDoc(bytes)

vtdGen.parse(true)
print("***************************************************")
print("Parsing method is called and imposed")
val vn = vtdGen.getNav()
val pilot = new AutoPilot(vn)
pilot.selectXPath(xpath)

  println("Xpath :::"+xpath)
  //    println("pilot.selctXPath(xpath)  ::: "+pilot.selectXPath(xpath))
  println("pilot.evalXPathToString ::: "+pilot.evalXPathToString())

  if (xpath.contains("/@")) {
    println("if loop")
    value = pilot.evalXPathToString()
  } else {
    println("else loop : " + pilot.evalXPath())
    println("vn.getText ::"+ vn.getText)
    while (pilot.evalXPath != -1) {
      println("vn " + vn)
      if (vn.getText != -1) {
        value = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText)
      }
      value
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note that I am writting a program which is UTF agnostic. It works with UTF-8 XML files. But while parsing UTF -16 xml files, I am getting the exception.

Comment: you need to change the xml declaration so that UTF-16Be is specified in the xml document... did you forget to do that?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author   I have XML file with UTF-16 declaration.  Is that what you are referring to?
Below is the sample XML i am using.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
            <request
            xmlns="http://www.test.com/text/xsd/textm/test.xsd">
            <header> 
   <aid>abc92</aid>
            <iname>1.2.3.4</iname>
            <operation>Beware</operation>
            <retryCount>0</retryCount> 
   <input>
            <Details>
            <xid>1234</xid>
            <cal>8765</cal>
            <textnumber>11234</textnumber>
            <type>file</type> 
   </Details>
   </input>
            </request>

Comment: I think you might need to include a byte order mask if the utf-16 be or LE is not specified... they are a pair of 8 bit chars, either ff fe or ff ff

Comment: @vtd-xml-author, Could you be more illustrative, I could not follow up on your above statement. I already have XML with UTF-16 (see the above sample XML i have pasted).

Answer (score 0):

What I meant by byte order mask is a sequence of 2 16-bit chars that tells the xml parser the encoding of subsequent document.

If your document is utf-16BE encoded..the first two chars should be 0xfe 0xff.

Otherwise, the first two chars should be 0xff 0xfe...

You can open up the hex viewer/editor to check the document header.